# Как проверить одновременно много условий Python?

Tags: python, оптимизация, if, условия, pyautogui

Всем привет! Работал с pyautogui и столкнулся с проблемой, очень долго выполняется код. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ быстро проверить много условий?

```
import pyautogui
while True:

    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('car.jpg', confidence=0.9,grayscale=True, region=(REGION)):
        print("found!")

    elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen('car2.jpg', confidence=0.9,grayscale=True, region=(REGION)):
        print("found!")

    elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen('car3.jpg', confidence=0.9,grayscale=True, region=(REGION)):
        print("found!")

    elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen('car4.jpg', confidence=0.9,grayscale=True, region=(REGION)):
        print("found!")

    elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen('car5.jpg', confidence=0.9,grayscale=True, region=(REGION)):
        print("found!")

    else:
        print("not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать асинхронную библиотеку asyncio

```
import pyautogui
import asyncio

list_car = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png']

async def t(i):
    
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(list_car[i], confidence=0.9,grayscale=True):
        print("found!")
    else:
        print("not found")

    print(list_car[i])

async def start():
    i = 0
    while True:
        await t(i)
        i += 1

asyncio.run(start())
```

Comment: Ну, вы пишите асинхронный код, но в цикле дожидаетесь выполнения каждой из функций, т.е. разницы  с первоначальным кодом фактически нет. Чтобы выполнялось параллельно, нужно результат корутин через gather собирать, ну и вызывать `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` нужно через `asyncio.to_thread`, т.к. функция блокирует основной поток и не даст выполняться другим функциям параллельно с ней.